# AbstractControl.setErrors does not stick in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

```js
@ViewChild('adjustmentTemplateForm')
private adjustmentTemplateForm: NgForm;

onInputChanged(): void {
  let formField: AbstractControl = this.adjustmentTemplateForm.form.controls[parameterValueField];

  if (1 == 1) {
    formField.setErrors({
      "notUnique": true
    });
    parameterValueObject.isParameterValueValid = false;
  } else {
    this.form.setErrors(null);
    parameterValueObject.isParameterValueValid = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form #adjustmentTemplateForm="ngForm" novalidate>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myVal" (ngModelChange)="onInputChanged()" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

So on the sample above, after the line "parameterValueObject.isParameterValueValid = false;" has executed, "this.adjustmentTemplateForm.valid" will return false as long as I am still in the onInputChanged() method.  If I come back to this method again or pass the form object, "this.adjustmentTemplateForm.valid" will return true. I need to be able to manually set this form to be valid and invalid depending on the validation done on the onInputChanged().

Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a plunker, I cannot piece these two code snippets together, only thing I see in common is the form name :)

Comment: Im having this same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: any solution for this?